# BASS.NET: Retrieving tags from file with image is incredibly slow

Tags: c#, audio, bass

I'm using BASS.NET to power a music streaming program that I'm making. When I load audio files into my program, I also cache the tags of the file upon loading them so that I don't have to re-load every time I want to get a tag.

However, I stumbled upon an issue where, if the file has an image embedded in the tags, it can take between 2-5 seconds for the `BASS_TAG_BASS_TAG_GetFromFile` call to complete. With playlists consisting of thousands of files, this is completely unacceptable.

I was wondering if there was some way to prevent the BassTags addon from loading the image, or if there is some other solution that I don't know of.

I load the files with `tempID = Bass.BASS_StreamCreateFile(file, 0, 0, BASSFlag.BASS_DEFAULT)` and then retrieve the tags with `BassTags.BASS_TAG_GetFromFile(tempID, tags)`.